# Video stream from Windows USB device is upside down using AForge

Tags: c#, windows-7-x64, aforge

I am using [AForge.net version 2.25](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/) to display video feed from a USB digital microscope, [Celestron 44302-B](http://Celestron%20Deluxe%20Handheld%20Digital%20Microscope%20-%2044302-B).  Using the software for the microscope, video displayed properly on a Windows 7 x64 workstation.

Code is based on sample application with Aforge.  The result is shown below where the video feed in  AForge.Controls.videoSourcePlayer is upside down.

I can easily flip a single bitmap (snapshot taken from the video stream) but I want to allow the user to orient and focus the microscope while the video feed is connected and running.

```
using AForge.Controls
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;

void connectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      VideoCaptureDevice _videoDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(_videoDevices[devicesCombo.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);

        if (_videoDevice != null)
        {
            if ((_videoCapabilities != null) && (_videoCapabilities.Length != 0))
            {
                _videoDevice.VideoResolution = _videoCapabilities[videoResolutionsCombo.SelectedIndex];
            }

            if ((_snapshotCapabilities != null) && (_snapshotCapabilities.Length != 0))
            {
                _videoDevice.ProvideSnapshots = true;
                _videoDevice.SnapshotResolution = _snapshotCapabilities[snapshotResolutionsCombo.SelectedIndex];
                _videoDevice.SnapshotFrame += videoDevice_SnapshotFrame;

            }

           EnableConnectionControls(false);
           videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource = _videoDevice;              
           videoSourcePlayer.Start();

        }

}
```

[image: Celestron 44302-B]

[Test using microscope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Nj0h.jpg)
[image: Video feed using Aforge.net]

Comment: Are you sure the microscope isn't back to front?

Comment: I don't think so because I had initially used DirectShowLib-2005 and the video orientation was correct. However, the DirectShowLib was a bit buggy and occasionally the video feed would lock up requiring my app to be restarted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the NewFrame from event from Aforge.Controls.videoSourcePlayer.

Subscribe to the event before starting the video feed:

```
 videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource = _videoDevice;
 videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource.NewFrame += VideoSource_NewFrame; 
 videoSourcePlayer.Start();
```

and I tried this code:

```
private void VideoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
   eventArgs.Frame.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipXY);
}
```

But that did not work which I thought from the documentation should have rotated the new frame but did not display it in the videoSourcePlayer.

Solution is to display the rotated bitmaps into a picturebox and hide the videoplayer.

```
private void VideoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
      Mirror filter = new Mirror(true, true);
      filter.ApplyInPlace(img);
      pbxCamera.Image = img;
}
```

[image: Rotated image]

Comment: Pardon me for posting own my answer to this question so quickly.  I just wanted to share my I learned.  I will accept for the best answer posted by someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for posting this comment so late.
About your first solution that didn't work, you should add the NewFrame event on the VideoCaptureDevice object instead of the VideoSource. This way it should work

Answer (score 1):

You can use code:

```
 _videoDevice.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(videoSource_NewFrame);
 videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource = _videoDevice;
 videoSourcePlayer.Start();
```

and:

```
private void videoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    eventArgs.Frame.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
}
```

This works for me.